# Use different shell commands depending on the name of an input file

Tags: snakemake

I am trying to align RNA-seq data using Salmon, however because I work with a variety of mouse strains the genome index required will depend on the strain of mouse. I keep this information in the file name so the idea is that if the input file has a specific name then a certain index should be used, otherwise another index should be used.

This script runs perfectly and returns all the files I need, however, it will always use the shell command in the **else** statement, and completely ignores the **if** statement despite the file names technically being identical.

I've tried various things and have been unsuccessful, so I would also like to know the best way (not necessarily the most generalizable since this pipeline is only for my use) to accomplish what I would like.

Code:

```
rule salmon_mapping:
        input:
                fastq="data/raw_data/{sample}.fastq.gz",
                c57_index="/gpfs/data01/glasslab/home/cag104/refs/Mus_musculus/Ensemble/C57/Salmon_Index/",
                aj_index="/gpfs/data01/glasslab/home/cag104/refs/Mus_musculus/Ensemble/AJ/Salmon_Index/"
        log:
                "logs/salmon/{sample}_quant.log"
        params:
                prefix="{sample}"
        output:
                "data/processed_data/{sample}/quant.sf",
                "data/processed_data/{sample}/cmd_info.json"
        run:
                if {input.fastq} == "data/raw_data/mouse_AJ_M_Liver_Hepatocyte_RNA_notx_CG_1_VML_s20180131_GTCCGC.fastq.gz" or {input.fastq} == "data/raw_data/mouse_AJ_M_Liver_Hepatocyte_RNA_notx_CG_2_VML_s20180131_GTGAAA.fastq.gz":
                        shell("salmon quant -p 16 -i {input.aj_index} -l A -r <(gunzip -c {input.fastq}) -o data/processed_data/{wildcards.sample} &> {log}")
                else:
                        shell("salmon quant -p 16 -i {input.c57_index} -l A -r <(gunzip -c {input.fastq}) -o data/processed_data/{wildcards.sample} &> {log}"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `{input.fastq}` in `if` statement, but not in `shell` statement, with `input.fastq`. In your example, `input.fastq` is a string, which is what you want, whereas `{input.fastq}` makes it a python `set` object.

Comment: Let me go ahead and give this a shot. I read somewhere about the {} being output as a set object and had previously attempted to do str({input.fastq}) as a work-around and that hadn't worked. Unfortunately the documentation isn't very clear about this.

Will report back and give you the check mark! Thanks!

Comment: I would use the wildcard object instead of input objet `if wildcards.sample == "mouse_AJ_M_Liver_Hepatocyte_RNA_notx_CG_1_VML_s20180131_GTCCGC" or ...`

Answer (score 1):

Use a function that defines the input to your rule based on your wildcards.

```
def select_fastq_and_index(wildcards):
    fq = "data/raw_data/{sample}.fastq.gz".format(sample = wildcards["sample"])
    idx = ""
    if wildcards["sample"] in [             
    "mouse_AJ_M_Liver_Hepatocyte_RNA_notx_CG_1_VML_s20180131_GTCCGC",
    "mouse_AJ_M_Liver_Hepatocyte_RNA_notx_CG_2_VML_s20180131_GTGAAA"
        ]:
            idx = foo
    else:
            idx = bar
    return fq, idx
```

Then rewrite your rule:

```
rule salmon_mapping:
        input:
                select_fastq_and_index
        log:
                "logs/salmon/{sample}_quant.log"
        params:
                prefix="{sample}"
        output:
                "data/processed_data/{sample}/quant.sf",
                "data/processed_data/{sample}/cmd_info.json"
        shell: """
            salmon quant -p 16 -i {input[1]} -l A \
            -r <(gunzip -c {input[0]}) \
            -o data/processed_data/{wildcards.sample} \
            &> {log}
            """
```